# Stop audio when enter room in Gamemaker?

Tags: game-maker

Having some trouble with getting audio to stop playing when you enter a specified room.  I've tried a few different ways, including coding it completely using if statements and audio_play_sound/audio_stop_sound and audio_play_music/audio_stop_music, but both of those didn't work and just layered the music over and over until it created a mess of sound.

Currently, I've tried to do it this way, but upon entering the room the music just keep playing and won't stop.

[image: Here's the screenshot.]

Anyone know how to get this to work? 
I'm using the latest version of Gamemaker.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the **audio_stop_sound()** method accepts an instance of the sound, rather than the name of your sound object.

I'm doing this without Game Maker Studio here to verify the code, but the best way to do this is to save the index returned when you start a sound, and use that index later on to stop it.

For example to start your sound (called MainMenuTheme):

```
global.MENU_SOUND = audio_play_sound(MainMenuTheme, 1, 1);
```

Then to stop it

```
if (audio_is_playing(global.MENU_SOUND)) 
{
    audio_stop_sound(global.MENU_SOUND);
}
```

Basically when you start a looping sound, store its index in a global variable so you are able to stop it when you need to, from a different screen or object.